# Can't read RSS feed with xmlTextReader - "A column named 'link' already belongs to this DataTable"

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, rss, xmltextreader

I've been using an xmlDataReader to read RSS for many years, but all of a sudden two feeds I've use have introduced an extra line which is tripping up the xmlDataReader parser.

The problem is the second line here conflicts with the first:

```
<link>http://www.eventjobsearch.co.uk/jobsrss/</link>
<atom:link href="http://www.eventjobsearch.co.uk/jobsrss/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
```

The parser thinks the atom:link element is a duplicate of the link element.  I don't personally need the atom:link line but as I'm using a stream, I can't see any way to remove this line or remove the colon (which would solve the problem).

How can I get rid of the colon in the stream so the built in parser works again?

```
 HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XmlJobsFeedUrl"]);
 req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)"; 

 WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
 Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
 XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
 DataSet jobs = new DataSet("Jobs");
 jobs.ReadXml(xmlTextReader);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4349748/265165) and [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4355030/265165). Straight before calling `jobs.ReadXml(...)`, you can read the schema:

```
jobs.ReadXmlSchema("http://www.thearchitect.co.uk/schemas/rss-2_0.xsd");
```

It's probably recommended to copy the xsd file to your own server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you could probably do this:

```
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
Stream cleanStream = new Stream();

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cleanStream))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // if the line doesn't match the problem then write it to the stream like this
            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}

// and now use the cleanStream instead
XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(cleanStream);
```

and that should allow you to clean the stream you've received.